# UIWebView loads with error code -1008

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Just playing around the `UIWebView`, I found some very interesting case...
When I hit a site with some xls file (say *www.econ.yale.edu/~shiller/data/ie_data.xls*) and now visit any other site and go back to the previous visited xls file. this file loads with an error and

```
webView(_ webView: UIWebView,didFailLoadWithError error: NSError?)
```

gets called with following error "resource unavailable", here is the destription

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1008 "resource unavailable" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=x-apple-ql-id://02C2F712-77CE-4015-8237-31BB4B203221/x-apple-ql-magic/Sheet0.html, NSLocalizedDescription=resource unavailable, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=x-apple-ql-id://02C2F712-77CE-4015-8237-31BB4B203221/x-apple-ql-magic/Sheet0.html}
```

So guys I really curious to know what is this error all about and what -1008 error code says.

**Note:** This happens only in case of  **xls** file

Comment: This error means `kCFURLErrorResourceUnavailable`,     //-1008

Comment: @iSashok but that error is fake, the resource that `xls` file is right there.